# Unable to run angularJS application (1.6) in visual studio after enabling script debug

Tags: javascript, angularjs, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

I am working on an angular 1.6 application and I am a total beginner in that. The solution contains one asp.net web api project which runs first and then we run the angular project.

It was working fine but I wanted to check the value of a parameter in angular side, so I added a debugger on JS side assuming that I might see the value this way.
Now since I did that I have not been able to run the angular project properly and I am getting this error constantly,

[image: Error popup]

after getting the below error the application gives me another error and it closes the build as well

[image: img2]

I am totally new to angular

Comment: I guess you have checked the option `JavaScript debugging for Asp.Net (Chrome, Edge and IE)` under Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General. Besides,1. try to close VS and Chrome, then open Chrome via as administrator, then  re-login your account  and test again. 2.change another browser such as firefox. 3. restart your PC and test again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Unable to run angularJS application (1.6) in visual studio after
>   enabling script debug

**Based** on your description, I think this issue is more related to your vs environment, so please try these steps to troubleshoot your issue:

First, I guess you have checked the option `JavaScript debugging for Asp.Net (Chrome, Edge and IE)` under `Tools` -> `Options` -> `Debugging` -> `General`.

**1.** try to close VS and Chrome, then open Chrome via as administrator, then re-login your account and test again.

**2.** restart your PC and test again

**3.** change another browser such as firefox while debugging.